# Datetime search in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/20480/1)

```
CREATE TABLE STUDY
(
  [ID][INT],
  STUDY_DATE VARCHAR(40),
  START_TIME VARCHAR (40),
  END_TIME VARCHAR (40)

)

INSERT INTO STUDY VALUES(1,'2013-12-23','11:30:00','11:31:00')


SELECT STUDY_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME
FROM STUDY
WHERE (STUDY_DATE >='2013-12-22'
AND CAST(START_TIME AS DATETIME) >='19:12:01')
AND (STUDY_DATE <='2013-12-23' 
AND CAST(END_TIME AS DATETIME) <='13:12:14')
```

i have to fetch records from table with above criteria..
however my STUDY_DATE criteria is fullfill but START_TIME criteria not.
thats the reason records not fetch from table..
What should i do.

Comment: Why dates are stored using a VARCHAR columns ? Which SQL Server version ?

Comment: SQL Server 2008......

Comment: Starting from SQL Server 2008 you can use DATE & TIME data types ([MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733(v=sql.105).aspx)). First, instead of using VARCHAR to store date and time values you have to use DATE and TIME types. Then, `START_TIME` values (ex. '19:12:01') shouldn't be less than `END_TIME` values (ex. '13:12:14') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example - '11:30:00' IS NOT more or equal '19:12:01' (when casted to datetime, but it doesnt matter).
Do what people suggest - store date as datetime, dont use varchars for it.

Upd:

Ok, if you cant change your table:

```
SELECT STUDY_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME
FROM STUDY
WHERE CAST(STUDY_DATE + 'T' + START_TIME  AS DATETIME)  >='2013-12-22T19:12:01'
     AND CAST(STUDY_DATE + 'T' + END_TIME  AS DATETIME) <='2013-12-23T13:12:14'
```

Comment: At this time not able to change datatype varchar to datetime

Comment: well, than you have to convert (study_date + start_time) and (study_date + end_time) together to datetime

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you store your date fields as varchar...

When you cast START_TIME field as DATETIME its representation is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.mmm

So you can't compare your casted field with 19:12:01 but you must take the time part (DATEPART function can help you) and then you'll compare with your constant (19:12:01).

I've seen your SqlFiddle. You can't cast as datetime the value 11:30:00.

- Solution A: Change the field type (adviced)
- Solution B: Compare as string your values, because is a well formed string (not adviced)

Comment: Joe How should be my query then

Comment: I've written in Solution A: Change the field type. (conseguentely the field value) so use DATEPART function to retrieve the time information

Answer (score 0):

Although it's better use proper data types (`datetime` in this case) if you can't change data types for this fields you can add [computed columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and even create indexes on them (for PERSISTED).

```
CREATE TABLE #STUDY
(
  [ID][INT],
  STUDY_DATE VARCHAR(40),
  START_TIME VARCHAR (40),
  END_TIME VARCHAR (40),
  START_DATETIME AS CAST(REPLACE(STUDY_DATE,'-','')+' '+START_TIME as datetime),
  END_DATETIME AS CAST(REPLACE(STUDY_DATE,'-','')+' '+END_TIME as datetime)
)

INSERT INTO #STUDY VALUES(1,'2013-12-23','11:30:00','11:31:00')


SELECT STUDY_DATE,START_TIME,END_TIME
FROM #STUDY
WHERE START_DATETIME >='20131222 19:12:01'
AND END_DATETIME <='20131223 13:12:14'


drop table #STUDY
```

Comment: i also strongly recommend using date,time or one column with datetime datatype and you are never in such mess.see

WHERE (cast(STUDY_DATE as date) >=cast('2013-12-22' as date)
AND CAST(START_TIME AS TIME) >=cast('19:12:01' as time))
similarly do for other .